# One profile image to rule them all

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile, profile-picture

Why my stack exchange profile picture is not replicated to all my stack exchange logins?

It appears only in stackoverflow profile.

I registered and login with my google account.

I don't use gravatar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just follow these steps,

- Go to your profile page,
- Click on Edit link,
- After selecting proper image, click on the big command button named "Save and Copy Profile to All Stack Exchange Account"

See the image,

[image]

Comment: What if all you want to change is the picture, not the entire profile?

Answer (score 5):

Since you can setup a different profile image on every site, it wouldn't be a good idea to update *all* of the profile images on all of the sites if you just updated it one one site.

In order to update it on every site you are on, click `edit` on your profile page then click the `Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts` button.

[image: Save And copy to all accounts]

Comment: ha ha ... we are writing same thing at almost same time :)

Comment: @Raynold but you arguably have the nicer freehand circle. Oded's looks like it's starving.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks, yeah i thought same.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - it's on a diet.

Comment: thanks guys! I accepted the Raynold's one because he has less reputation points