# updating profile after acct's been created doesn't update other sites

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile

Yesterday, I changed my Location on Stack Overflow and thought the change would be reflected on meta stackoverflow but apparently it wasn't. I guess that's just supported?

I could see some problems if it takes time to copy over. Like if you make a change stackoverflow on your profile and then make a chance on metastackoverflow before your stackoverflow changes have had a chance to propagate over but it seems like that could be mitigated recording the time that each change was made and just applying the latest change.

Comment: Did you click the save profile or the save and change on all stack exchange accounts button? (button text may not be exact)

Comment: See this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171451/140505

Comment: I did not know about that lol - thanks for the heads up!