# Change profile image globally

Tags: support, profile-picture

I changed my profile picture two weeks ago using the "upload picture" functionality on Stack Overflow. On my [Network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1399208/w4rumy) and [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1328300/w4rumy), the new image shows fine. However, on my other profiles ([example)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/6299/w4rumy), it still shows the old image.

I cleared browser cache and used a different browser, so it does not seem to be a caching problem on my side. How can I change my profile picture globally, so that it is the same on every SE site?

Comment: You can see my answer here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171451/214722

Comment: Yeah I see this is a duplicate so you can close it of course. But I do not understand the downvotes, what is wrong with the question itself? Beside that I tried to find the answer before but I could not find it.

Comment: i didnt downvoted your question. I just paste my answer's link.

Comment: @Raynold I didn't suspect you who downvoted, I just saw some downvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change your profile in all networks you need to edit your profile instead of direct changing your profile.

Just click on edit profile, change the profile picture and click `Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts`. This will change your profile picture in all your Stack Exchange profile.

Comment: That's solved it, thanks! I was not aware of this. Now I am colored on all Stackexchange sites :D

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the "Save and copy profile to all Stack Exchange accounts" button while editing. The Network profile shows the profile which was last edited.

Alternatively, use the Gravatar upload.
[image]

Comment: -1 No efforts for freehand circle.