# Synchronize/change Area51 profile image

Tags: bug, area-51, profile-picture, synchronization

I just visited [my Area51 account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/46349/juergen-d) and noticed that my profile picture is not the same as on all other sites.

According to [this recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179276/change-profile-image-globally) the image will be synchronized when synchronizing the complete profile. I did that but the image is still the same.

Then I wanted to change the image in the Area51 profile directly - but I can only change to a gravatar image and can't use the new and fancy Stack Exchange image.

Is that a bug?

Comment: It wants you to go back to beaker.

Comment: I would assume Area51 never got the new image build deployed and as such can only use your gravatar.