# Delete an unregistered account

Tags: bug, area-51

I committed to an Area 51 proposal and somewhere along the line where I logged in with my Stack Exchange account it somehow got my personal photo, my name and other information and linked me to this commit.

How do I **NOT** use a new unregistered account, but instead use my real stack exchange account? I never logged in with anything other than my Stack Exchange account...

Edit: Is there something wrong with Area 51? It seems to create a new account for me that's relatively blank when I go there, and cannot use my image from here.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Area 51 is a bit odd. When I signed up for it originally, it took a day to actually "stick" that I was registered and logged in.

Comment: Also, * cannot use my image from here.* - See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185694/synchronize-change-area51-profile-image , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179276/change-profile-image-globally.

Comment: Gravatar is a good idea, but honestly the worst bloody implementation I've ever seen.